# Collecting multiple values separately from Python Dictionaries with keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, tuples

I have a dictionary D like this:

```
    {'A': ['0.4', '4'], 'C': ['0.1', '4'], 'B': ['0', '0'], 'D': ['0.5', '5']}
```

I understand that doing the below in a loop:

```
    P = [lambda: d[rx]]
    print P[0]()
```

gives:

```
    ['0.4', '4']
    ['0.1', '1']
    ['0', '0']
    ['0.5', '5']
```

OR doing:

```
     print D.values()
```

gives:

```
    [['0.4', '4'], ['0.1', '1'], ['0', '0'], ['0.5', '5']]
```

How can I get only **single values** separately for **each key**?

**I want to assign each of the corresponding values to a variable like below:**

eg: for key A, i want to get the values 0.4 and 4 separately and assign them like this somehow.

```
    floating = 0.4
    numeral = 4
```

Comment: `for sublist in d.values(): first, second  = sublist`?

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension should do?

floats = [_.[0] for _ in D.values()]

numerals = [_.[1] for _ in D.values()]

Answer (score 0):

you could use meta programming:

```
for k.v in D.items():
     exec("%s_floating = %f" % (k, v[0]))
     exec("%s_numeral = %d" % (k, v[1]))
```

then you can access A_floating, A_numeral, B_floating, B_numeral... etc...

Answer (score 0):

This should work?

```
    for key, value in D.iteritems():
            print key, value[1], value[2]
            floating = value[1]
            numeral = value[2]
```